# Is it possible to connect to database hosted in local machine through AWS lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I launched one RDS instance,s3 and EC2 in AWS and its is triggered properly using lambda. Now I wish to change the change the RDS and EC2 from AWS to local machine. My lambda is triggered from s3.

How do I connect the local database through lambda in AWS?

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with John Rotenstein that connecting your local machine to a Lambda running on AWS is probably a bad idea.

If your intention is to develop or test locally, I recommend the serverless framework, and the serverless-offline plugin.  It will allow you to simulate Lambda locally, and you can pass database config values through as environment variables.

See: [Running AWS Lambda and API Gateway locally: serverless-offline](https://medium.com/a-man-with-no-server/running-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-locally-serverless-offline-3c64b3e54772)

Answer (score 6):

It appears that your requirement is:

- You wish to run an AWS Lambda function
- Within the function, you wish to connect to a database running on your own computer (outside of AWS)

Firstly, **I would not recommend this strategy**. To maintain good performance, you should always have an application as close as possible to the database. This means on the same network, in the same location and *not* going across remote network connections or the Internet.

However, if you wish to do this, then here's some things you would need to do:

- **Your database will need to be accessible on the Internet**, so that you can connect to it remotely. To test this, try accessing it from an Amazon EC2 instance.
- The **AWS Lambda function** should either be configured without VPC connectivity (which means that it is connected to the Internet) or, if you have configured it for VPC connectivity, it needs to be in a Private Subnet with a NAT Gateway enabling Internet access.
- (Optional) For added security, you could **lock-down your database** to only accept connections from a known IP address. To achieve this, you would need to use the VPC + NAT Gateway so that all traffic is coming from the Elastic IP address assigned to the NAT Gateway.

Comment: Thanks, in my case the lambda was in a VPC