# Can cloud functions like AWS Lambdas or Google Cloud Function access databases from other servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, api-design, serverless

I have a webapp and database that aren't hosted on any cloud service, just on a regular hosting platform.

I need to build an API to read and write to that database and I want to use cloud functions to do so. Is it possible to connect to a remote databases from cloud functions (such as AWS Lambdas or Google cloud functions) even when they're not hosted that cloud service?

If so, can there be problems with doing so?

Comment: Kindly check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49878674/6215280

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions are just Node.js code that runs in a managed environment. This means your code can do almost anything that Node.js scripts can do, as long as you stay within the restrictions of that environment.

I've seen people connect to many other database services, both within Google Cloud Platform and outside of it. The main restriction to be aware of there, is that you'll need to be on a paid plan in order to be able to call APIs that are not running on Google Cloud Platform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

> If so, can there be problems with doing so?

There could high latency if the database is in a different network. Also, long-lived database connection pools don't really work well in these environments due to the nature of the functions being created and destroyed constantly. Also, if your function reaches a high level of concurrency you may exhaust the number of available connections on your database server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use FaaS the same as your web service hosted on any web server or cloud server.
You have to be careful with the duration of your call to DB because FasS functions are limited in time (15 min for AWS Lambda and 9 min on Google) and configure a firewall properly on your DB server.

A container of your lambda function could be reused, you could use some tricks with it - [Best Practices for AWS Lambda Container Reuse](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/best-practices-for-aws-lambda-container-reuse-6ec45c74b67e)

But you can't be sure that nothing changed during the work of your service.
You could read some good advice about it there - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37524237/182344

PS: Azure functions have [*always on* setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#always-on), but I am not sure how pooling will work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access on premise resources from Serverless products.

Please check this detailed tutorial where you can find 3 methods to achive your goal [link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-reach-on-premise-resources-with-serverless-products-747ebd37dc8e):

1. Connecting using a [VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/)
2. Connecting using a [Parner interconnect](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/partners/)
3. Connecting using [Interconnect solution](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/)